# Primary and secondary numerical sorting of file names by delimiter

Tags: gnu-sort

I have some files named like so:

```
S241R39.txt
S241R40.txt
S241R41.1.txt
S241R41.2.txt
S241R42.1.txt
S241R42.2.txt
```

I want to be able to sort these in this order:

```
S241R39.txt
S241R40.txt
S241R41.1.txt
S241R42.1.txt
S241R41.2.txt
S241R42.2.txt
```

Here, I want `41.1` to come before `42.1`, and `42.1` to come before `41.2`

In files that don't end in `.1` or `.2` this sorts my files correctly:

`ls -1 *.txt | sort -V`

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can adjust this to give me my desired output?

Comment: @ fugu...in what file manager you want that to be done? Very vague question info here. A filelist for text editor.... ? Add also some trial and error code of your attempts!

Comment: @ZF007 The tags should give you a hint that it is not about file managers or text editors but command line.

Comment: (This would probably fit better in unix.SE, but I still don't understand such a quick downvote hammering)

Comment: @ Würgspaß, ilkkachu..  the filemanager was a polite way of downvoting/ no research effort shown by OP whatsoever. The bash lookup shortcut when I need a cup of coffee and run around on my Linux systems while getting bored of filemanagers > wiki: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sort -t . -k2n -k1n`:

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt | sort -t . -k2n -k1V

S241R39.txt
S241R40.txt
S241R41.1.txt
S241R42.1.txt
S241R41.2.txt
S241R42.2.txt
```

`sort` command in use is:

- `-t .`: Make dot a field delimiter
- `-k2n -k1V`: Use sort by field2 (numeric), field1 (version)

Comment: possibly even `-k1V`, since that first part isn't really a number per se